# Vim command to go past a closing ) } ] " ' without pressing right arrow?

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin, neovim

I have this problem every time I use a ( or any of " ' { [. I have plugin that automatically closes it by corresponding ) " ' } ] but I am stuck inside the parenthesis or inside double quotes

```
String s="I completed typing the string but my cursor is stuck right here |";
```

I want exit the enclosure by pressing something for all. In VScode I can press the same symbol if my cursor is right behind it and it gets past the enclosure or by pressing tab
I can exit the enclosure without reaching for right arrow

Comment: What's wrong with the right arrow?

Comment: You can use `<c-o>` in insert mode to perform one normal mode command so depending on where you want to go, you could use `<c-o>A` to continue at the end,, `<c-o>o` to start a newline, ...

Comment: Many autopair plugins allow you to type the closer and move over it instead; does this not work with your plugin? Fwiw, i stopped using autopair-style plugins because it’s more convenient for me to write them myself

Comment: In lh-brackets I implement a _"jump after all following closing pairs"_, I even have some other shortcuts like `;` in C and C++ that closes all following compatible pairs and append a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin is '[jiangmiao/auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs)' it has a variable called g:AutoPairsShortcutJump you can set as you want or use the default tha is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>.

```
" Jump outside '"({  
" -> default Alt-n
if !exists('g:AutoPairsShortcutJump')
    let g:AutoPairsShortcutJump = '<A-l>'
endif
```

Note: If your cursor it close to the end atom you can just repeat that one to jump outside. For example:

Let's supose the character `|' represents your cursor

```
(|)
```

Just press closing parenthesis will jump outside